# $A:= \{y \in X | f(x) = f(y) \text{ for all measurable } f : X \longrightarrow \mathbb R\}$ is an atom

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

My definition of an atom : $A \in \mathcal U$ atom of measurable space ($ X, \mathcal U$) if from $A \supseteq B \in \mathcal U$ it follows that $B=A $ or $B = \emptyset$

Question :

For any $x \in X$ it follows that $A:= \{y \in X | f(x) = f(y) \text{ for all measurable } f : X \longrightarrow \mathbb R\}$ is an **atom**.

I already showed that for all measurable $f: X \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ it follows that $f$ is constant on atoms of $X$. Now I have trouble on showing this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is an atom if $A \in \mathcal{U}$. But it is possible that $A \notin \mathcal{U}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $A \supseteq B \in \mathcal U$ and $B$ is non-empty. Now we can construct a measurable function
$$
f: X \to \mathbb{R}: y \mapsto \left \{ \begin{matrix} 1 & \text{ if }  y \in B  \\
0 & \text{ if } y \not \in B \end{matrix} \right.
$$
This function is measurable, because $B$ is measurable. Now notice that either $f(x) =1$ or $f(x) =0$, so by construction of $A$ we must have $f^{-1}(0) =A$ or $f^{-1}(1) = A$. Since $B \subset A$ and $f^{-1}(0) =X \setminus B$, we must have $f^{-1}(1) =A$. But of course we also have $f^{-1}(1) =B$, proving that $A=B$.

Comment: Thank you alot this is very helpful